# Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opengl

I'm learning Opengl and I ran into this issue and couldn't solve it.
So here is the Error message I get after the window open with just the background:
`Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate`.

My script uses some basic modern Opengl abstracted into classes using numpy for the data in arrays. It just draws 2 triangles.

```
from PyE import App
from PyE.Opengl import VBuff, Shader

from numpy import array, float32
from OpenGL.GL import (
    glClear, glClearColor, glDrawArrays, glUseProgram,glEnableClientState,
    GL_TRIANGLES, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_FLOAT,GL_VERTEX_ARRAY
)


app = App(1080, 720, "Test Window")

glClearColor(.1,.1,.1,1.)


positions = [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

positions = array(positions, dtype=float32)

sh = Shader("test.sl")
vb = VBuff(positions, sh)

@app.mainLoop
def Draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    vb.bind()
    glUseProgram(sh.prog_id)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6)
    glUseProgram(0)
    vb.unbind()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Draw()
```

For more information, I'm on windows 10 using python 3.7.6.
Hope someone can help me ;) have a nice day.

Comment: Same issue, have you found any solution??

Comment: no I abandoned finding one and went on another project saddly

Comment: I have solved this issue by removing the accelerate library since it's the cause of the bug `pip uninstall PyOpenGL_accelerate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out.

You need to download and install packages from Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages.

You need to choose these packages:

- numpy (+mkl)
- scipy
- PyOpenGL
- PyOpenGL_accelerate
- pygame
- freeglut (MSVG)

How to find out which is the right one ?
Look at your Python version, for me it's 3.8.5 .
On the package name there is a "cp" with a number right next to it.
It correspond to the version of Python.
In my case i will take cp38 for python 3.8x

> *numpy-1.19.1+mkl-* **cp38** *-* **cp38** *-win_amd64.whl*

Once downloaded, simply install with pip. (Be-careful of the installation order).

```
pip install numpy-1.19.1+mkl-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pip install scipy-1.5.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

For GLUT, copy the freeglut.dll into C:/Windows directory.

```
copy freeglut.dll C:\Windows
```

**Links:**

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

[Freeglut Windows Development Libraries](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)

Comment: Do you know any way to verify if all installations were successful? `pip list` lists all packages and I copied the `freeglut.dll` into the windows directory but I still get the same error (Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate)

Comment: You may have a missing package or, one or more package with a different version than your python interpreter. Which is your current version ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and on win10. I download `PyOpenGL_accelerate` from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl), maybe pypi also is ok. And install offline, it works well.

Maybe the same problem as PyOpenGL. when use `pip install PyOpenGL` on windows, then will get the error message

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling
```

Also download whl, offline install to resolve.